# extensible enum

Tags: java, enums

I'm thinking about how one can write an extensible node-kind approach. Currently each node in a tree-structure must implement a method which returns the kind of node (currently an enum which defines how to serialize and deserialize nodes on disk depending on the kind of node). If a user wants to use the framework and define and implement other node-types we need some extensibility.

I thought about adding an interface (extensible enum pattern) and use somethink like

`public interface IKind` and in the node interface use something like `public <E extends Enum<E> & IKind> E getKind() {...}`. However I'm not even sure if that is ok:

```
@Override
public <T extends Enum<T> & IKind> T getKind() {
  return (T)ENode.ELEMENT_KIND;
}
```

for an ElementNode (XML) and an enum ENode which implements IKind. Furthermore it doesn't allow to switch on the kind of node which somehow seems to be a killer argument as one probably doesn't want to write a visitor implementation everytime.

The current implementation simply is:

```
@Override
public ENode getKind() {
  return ENode.ELEMENT_KIND;
}
```

I'm currently writing a simple PathSynopsis of a tree-structure and thus use PathNodes which I don't want to add to the core nodes.

BTW: Is it somehow possible to return any kind of an enum(value) to use with a switch-statement?... As one cannot switch on Enum.

Perhaps returning a simple byte value which is used for serialization/deserialization nontheless could also be used, but it's a bit ugly:

`switch (ENode.getKind(pNewRtx.getNode().getKind()))`

and

```
public enum ENode implements IKind {
  ELEMENT((byte) 0, ElementNode.class) {
    serialize(...) {...}
    deserialize(...) {...}
  }
  ...
  /** Mapping of keys -> nodes. */
  private static final Map<Byte, ENode> INSTANCEFORID = new HashMap<>();

  /** Mapping of class -> nodes. */
  private static final Map<Class<? extends INode>, ENode> INSTANCEFORCLASS = new HashMap<>();

  static {
    for (final ENode node : values()) {
      INSTANCEFORID.put(node.mId, node);
      INSTANCEFORCLASS.put(node.mClass, node);
    }
  }
  ...
  /**
   * Get the related node based on the identifier.
   * 
   * @param pId
   *          the identifier for the node
   * @return the related node value
   */
   public static ENode getKind(final byte pId) {
     return INSTANCEFORID.get(pId);
   }
```

with

```
public interface IKind {
  /**
   * Deserializing a node using a {@link ITTSource}.
   * 
   * @param pSource
   *          input source
   * @return a {@link INode} instance
   */
  INode deserialize(final ITTSource pSource);

  /**
   * Serializing a node from a {@link ITTSink}.
   * 
   * @param pSink
   *          where the data should be serialized to
   * @param pToSerialize
   *          the node to serialize
   */
  void serialize(final ITTSink pSink, final INode pToSerialize);

  /**
   * Get the nodeKind.
   * 
   * @return the unique kind
   */
  byte getKind();
}
```

However this would even introduce the possibility for NPEs and the implementers have to ensure that no byte-values are identical across implementations.

Answer (score 4):

When I write enums, they usually constitute a closed set.  I wouldn't go that route if they had to be dynamic.  I'd be more likely to think in terms of a common interface and polymorphism.

Comment: up until now they were a closed set (storage for XML-documents) but I think it's of more value as a framework to persistent revisioned tree-structured documents of any kind ;-)

Comment: I wouldn't do it using enums, then.  I don't disagree with your idea, just your choice of implementation.  I think it goes against the purpose of an enum.

Comment: Actually, with the method outlined above, you're both right.  The methods take Collections of interfaces.  The enum provides a default set of interface implementations.  Everybody wins.

Comment: "Can't we all just get along?"